# yum ignoring exclude directive in yum.conf

Tags: centos, yum, mysql

I need to hold back `mysql` from being updated in `yum update`.  I added `exclude=mysql*` to `/etc/yum.conf` as below:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=19&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
exclude=mysql*
```

When I issue `yum update` again, yum is still trying to update `mysql`

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.46-1.el6.remi will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.46-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.46-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-server-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.46-1.el6.remi
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.46-1.el6.remi
           Obsoleted By: Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 (percona-release-x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.46-1.el6.remi
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.46-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.46-1.el6.remi
           Obsoleted By: Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 (percona-release-x86_64)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

**Why is yum ignoring the exclude directive?**

Comment: Does it work if you perform the command in-line? `yum --exclude=mysql\* update`

Comment: nope - that didn’t work either.

Comment: I disabled the Percona repo and that cleared the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you exclude, best always use `*name*`. With `mysql*` you only excluded all packages whose name starts with mysql. In your example it also shows `real-mysql-libs` which would not have been excluded, hence it would attempt to resolve its dependencies but excluded the `mysql*` ones.

Better use `*mysql*`.

For what it's worth, the same applies for repositories. E.g. what many people don't know, `yum clean all` will only clean metadata for the currently enabled repositories.
Use `yum clean all --enablerepo="*"` and it will also clean all metadata and cached packages and so on for the disabled repositories.

Answer (score 0):

exclude just works on wildcard name matching of available packages, Eg. not installed ones. So, among other things, it doesn't follow obsoletes. The error says mysql is being obsoleted by Percona-Server-shared.

You can exclude Percona-Server-shared, or you could instead install the versionlock plugin; tell it to follow obsoletes; and versionlock mysql.

Answer (score -1):

Try `yum clean all` before `yum update`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  Same error as in question.

Comment: I disabled the Percona repo and that cleared the error.